# Android and Hibernate Validator - it is possible to use together?

Tags: java, android, hibernate, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I wonder if it is possible to use Hibernate Validator on Android. I tried but it looks like some javax packages are missing on Android platform (javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory).

Here is my code, dependency and error:

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();

compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.3.Final'
compile 'javax.el:javax.el-api:2.2.4'
compile 'org.glassfish.web:javax.el:2.2.4'

03-28 10:07:15.562    6477-6477/foo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: foo, PID: 6477
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.XmlParserHelper.<init>(XmlParserHelper.java:66)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser.<init>(ValidationXmlParser.java:60)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getBootstrapConfiguration(ConfigurationImpl.java:287)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.parseValidationXml(ConfigurationImpl.java:361)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:214)
            at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:110)
            at foo.FooActivity.onCreate(FooActivity.java:35)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/foo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.XmlParserHelper.<init>(XmlParserHelper.java:66)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser.<init>(ValidationXmlParser.java:60)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getBootstrapConfiguration(ConfigurationImpl.java:287)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.parseValidationXml(ConfigurationImpl.java:361)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:214)
            at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:110)
            at foo.FooActivity.onCreate(FooActivity.java:35)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 21 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: As kind of resources are available to Hybernate on PC can not be accessed on Cellphone, I am afraid it won't work. Lets hope there is a mobile version of hybernate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve this. Due to lack of xml packages we have to disable this option in configuration. Here is my proposed solution.

```
    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation
            .byDefaultProvider()
            .configure()
            .ignoreXmlConfiguration()
            .buildValidatorFactory();

    Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
```

It's necessary to have following dependencies:

```
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.3.Final'
compile 'javax.el:javax.el-api:2.2.4'
compile 'org.glassfish.web:javax.el:2.2.4'
```

For custom messages from strings resources, MessageInterpolator has to be implemented. First of all Application must be extended for access to global context all over project.

```
public class ApplicationContext extends Application {
    private static Application application;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        application = this;
    }

    public static Application getApplication() {
        return application;
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation
            .byDefaultProvider()
            .configure()
            .ignoreXmlConfiguration()
            .messageInterpolator(new MessageInterpolator() {
                @Override
                public String interpolate(String messageTemplate, Context context) {
                    int id = ApplicationContext.getApplication().getResources().getIdentifier(messageTemplate, "string", R.class.getPackage().getName());
                    return ApplicationContext.getApplication().getString(id);
                }

                @Override
                public String interpolate(String messageTemplate, Context context, Locale locale) {
                    return interpolate(messageTemplate, context);
                }
            })
            .buildValidatorFactory();
```

Example:

```
@NotEmpty(message = "error_empty")
private String foo;

<resources>
    <string name="error_empty">Cannot be empty</string>
</resources>
```