# How to use hibernate-validator in android studio

Tags: android, hibernate, validation, build.gradle, hibernate-validator

Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getAnnotatedInterfaces() exception while using hibernate 6.1.6 . I am using java 8 and want to use hibernate 6.1.6 for using Container element constraints.

The solution at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29327957/7614704) works fine but it's for version 5.1.3.Final.

My code and errors

```
Dependencies

compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.1.6.Final'
compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'jakarta.el', version: '3.0.3'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator-cdi', version: '6.1.6.Final'
```

Getting error

```
2020-10-11 09:52:13.515 20928-20928/com.applab.peermainactivity E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.applab.peermainactivity, PID: 20928
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getAnnotatedInterfaces()[Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedType; in class Ljava/lang/Class; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.Class' appears in /system/framework/core-oj.jar)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction.ValueExtractorDescriptor.determineValueExtractorDefinitions(ValueExtractorDescriptor.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction.ValueExtractorDescriptor.getValueExtractorDefinition(ValueExtractorDescriptor.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction.ValueExtractorDescriptor.<init>(ValueExtractorDescriptor.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction.ByteArrayValueExtractor.<clinit>(ByteArrayValueExtractor.java:16)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction.ValueExtractorManager.<clinit>(ValueExtractorManager.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.AbstractConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(AbstractConfigurationImpl.java:448)
    at com.applab.peermainactivity.BaseActivity.<clinit>(BaseActivity.java:27)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:41)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6826)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Base Activity

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.applab.peermainactivity.utilities.LogUtils;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;

@SuppressLint("Registered")
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final boolean DEBUG=true;
private static final Validator validator;

static {
     validator=Validation
            .byDefaultProvider()
            .configure()
            .ignoreXmlConfiguration()
            .buildValidatorFactory().getValidator();
}

public <T> Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> validate(T object,Class<?>... groups){
    Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations= validator.validate(object,groups);

    if (DEBUG){
        for (ConstraintViolation<T> constraintViolation:violations)
            LogUtils.log(constraintViolation);
    }
    return violations;
}

public <T> boolean isValid(T object,Class<?>... groups){
    return validate(object,groups).size()==0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.

The problem is clearly the missing method in the Android JDK but, for the built-in value extractors, we could probably avoid all this machinery and declare the `ValueExtractor` metadata statically instead of doing reflection calls, thus avoiding the usage of this method in the standard case.

I created https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-1812 to keep track of the issue.

Comment: Could you try the PR I created here: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/pull/1132 ? It should avoid calling this method.